# Why do the following RSpec tests pass, with no validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

Using RSpec 3.1.7 with Rails 4.1.8.

I cannot work out why I get 0 failures, when I have created the tests but no validations. If I create a dummy validation on say 'exchange' testing for a minimum length of 10 then I get a failure.So the validation process seems to be triggered in that case. The test log does not give any clues.

spec/factory/tics.rb:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :tic do
    exchange {Faker::Address.state_abbr}
    code {Faker::Address.state_abbr}
    day {Faker::Date}
    price {Faker::Commerce.price}
    volume {Faker::Number} 
  end
end
```

spec/models/tics_specs.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Tic, :type => :model do

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:tic)).to be_valid
  end

# These are ActiveRecord validations so use Create not Build??
  it "is invalid without an exchange" do
    expect{(FactoryGirl.create(:tic, exchange: ''))}.to raise_error
  end

  it "is invalid without a code" do
    expect{(FactoryGirl.create(:tic, code: ''))}.to    raise_error 
  end

  it "is invalid without a day" do
    expect{(FactoryGirl.create(:tic, day: ''))}.to raise_error 
  end

  it "is invalid without a price" do
    expect {(FactoryGirl.create(:tic, price: 0))}.to raise_error
  end  

end
```

app/models/tic.rb:

```
class Tic < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: how are you running the tests? Do you have a `Rakefile`?

Comment: $ bundle exec rspec/models - no I'm not using a Rakefile.

Comment: Where is :log_tic defined?

Comment: Sorry - that's a typo on my part. Changed those to tic and now get a single failure on day, but not on exchange, code or price.

Comment: If you change `raise_error` to `be_valid` what is the error that shows up?

Comment: I have changed all to 'be_valid' and now get 4 failures. So have I been misusing 'raise_error'? By the way I expect these not to be valid - how do I express that?

Comment: Have downloaded the RSpec 3 version of EveryDayRails. I expect working through this will answer most of my questions. Thanks to those who responded.